# How do I prevent \hline from overrunning the edge of my table?

Tags: tables, hline

Here is my minimal working example :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\small
\begin{tabularx}{1.33\textwidth}{ |c|c|c|c| }
  \hline
    Date            & Type  & Color & Notes \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Output :
[image]

Notice the `\hline` run past the fourth column.

Question :
How do I get the `\hline` to terminate at the end of the last column?

Comment: Should the four columns have equal widths? Should their contents be centered or left-aligned? What are you trying to achieve by (a) setting the relative font size to `\small` while also (b) setting the width of the `tabularx` environment to `1.33\textwidth`?

Comment: Also 1.33\textwdith may be off the page and will definitely give a overfull \hbox error.  Unless you were planning to do this in landscape, in which case you should use \linewidth.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options. Simplest is that if you really want to use `tabularx`, you must use at least one "X" column. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\small
\begin{tabularx}{1.33\textwidth}{|c|c|c|X|}
  \hline 
   Date & Type  & Color & Notes \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

- It is not clear, what is your table content.
- Does each table's cell has only one line text? if it so, than tabular` will solve your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\small
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline 
   Date & Type  & Color & Notes \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- I cases, when for example, in the last column cells contents are multi line texts, than the use of the `tabularx` could be handy solution. IN this case at least one column had to be of `X` (or derivative from it, as is used in the following example) type:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|c|c|X|}
    \hline
Date     & Type      & Color & Notes         \\
    \hline
today    & Unknown   & b/w   & \lipsum[66]   \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

(observe difference how is determined table width, with `\linewidth` it is always accommodate to available space for the table; regardless if it is in portrait or landscape orientation)

[image]

- you may consider to use `tabularray`, a new powerful LaTeX-3 package for writing tables. Using it the second example (slightly redesigned) could be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,Z} = 0.6pt, hline{3-Y}=solid,
             vlines,
             colspec = {c c c X[j]},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries}
             }
Date     & Type      & Color & Notes         \\
yesterday& Unknown   & b/w   & \lipsum[11]   \\
today    & Unknown   & b/w   & \lipsum[66]   \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

(as you can see, using `tabularray` package it is not need to specify table width, if it is desired, that its width is equal to available space for it)